# Different python behave among different SSH login?

Tags: linux, character-encoding, ntfs, python-unicode

I have some NTFS disks mounted in CentOS, and some of the file name is Chinese. I login into Centos via Mac's `iTerm`, but when in my office Mac,        the `ls` shows the correct Chinese file name, but in home Mac, the `ls` just show something like `??????????????????`, and the most important is, my python script can not handle these files (`UnicodeDecodeError`) when I start it in my home Mac, but when started in office Mac, it works well.

Why this happen? How to fix it?

Except some ENV settings among tow different Mac, the python script is the same, and the disks also the same, why get exception when started on home Mac? also related to some ENV?

Comment: It depends a lot on how the file names are encoded, and on the capabilities of your file system.  A hex dump of the bytes in a (short) file name on both platforms would help clarify what we are dealing with here.  Also maybe see the [`character-encoding` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) for troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the answer. The ssh login do not accept the `LC_ALL` on the destination machine, even though the environment been set on that machine.  So, when run Python script, the `LC_ALL` value do not send to python script, and can not process these Chinese named files.

For C point of view, the `main()` function normally got 2 parameters:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

but actually, there is another one:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[])
```

and suddenly, I find the answer.

To avoid the same issue happen again, you can add a `export` to your start script or set `sshd_config`